# How to constrain objects in a box/cylinder container in Physijs (with Three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

I wrote a program to randomly generate and put ConvexGeometry object into a box container based on Physijs's example [shapes](http://chandlerprall.github.com/Physijs/examples/shapes.html).

Everything goes well until too many objects are put into the container, objects just struggle to fly out of the box .

Here is the code to initialize scene:

```
initScene = function() {
    TWEEN.start();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    document.getElementById( 'viewport' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    render_stats = new Stats();
    render_stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    render_stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    render_stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    document.getElementById( 'viewport' ).appendChild( render_stats.domElement );

    physics_stats = new Stats();
    physics_stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    physics_stats.domElement.style.top = '50px';
    physics_stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    document.getElementById( 'viewport' ).appendChild( physics_stats.domElement );

    scene = new Physijs.Scene({ fixedTimeStep: 1 / 120 });
    scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3( 0, -30, 0 ));
    scene.addEventListener(
        'update',
        function() {
            scene.simulate( undefined, 2 );
            physics_stats.update();
        }
    );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        35,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        1,
        1000
    );
    camera.position.set( 150, 120, 150 );
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    scene.add( camera );

    // Materials
    wall_material = Physijs.createMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true, transparent: true, opacity: 1 } )
    );
    ground_material = Physijs.createMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/rocks.jpg' ) }),
        .8, // high friction
        .4 // low restitution
    );
    ground_material.map.wrapS = ground_material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    ground_material.map.repeat.set( 2.5, 2.5 );

    // Ground
    ground = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 1, 50),
        //new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50),
        ground_material,
        0 // mass
    );

    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( ground );

    // Bumpers
    var bumper,
        bumper_geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 50, 50);

    // Back left
    bumper = new Physijs.BoxMesh( bumper_geom, ground_material, 0, { restitution: .2 } );
    bumper.position.y = 25;
    bumper.position.x = -25;
    bumper.receiveShadow = true;
    bumper.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( bumper );

    // Front right
    bumper = new Physijs.BoxMesh( bumper_geom, wall_material, 0, { restitution: .2 } );
    bumper.position.y = 25;
    bumper.position.x = 25;
    bumper.receiveShadow = true;
    bumper.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( bumper );

    // Back right
    bumper = new Physijs.BoxMesh( bumper_geom, wall_material, 0, { restitution: .2 } );
    bumper.position.y = 25;
    bumper.position.z = -25;
    bumper.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
    bumper.receiveShadow = true;
    bumper.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( bumper );

    // Front left
    bumper = new Physijs.BoxMesh( bumper_geom, wall_material, 0, { restitution: .2 } );
    bumper.position.y = 25;
    bumper.position.z = 25;
    bumper.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
    bumper.receiveShadow = true;
    bumper.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( bumper );

    // Top
    bumper = new Physijs.BoxMesh( bumper_geom, wall_material, 0, { restitution: .2 } );
    bumper.position.y = 50;
    bumper.position.x = 0;
    bumper.position.z = 0;
    bumper.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
    bumper.receiveShadow = true;
    bumper.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( bumper );

    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    scene.simulate();

    createShape();
};
```

Create shapes:

```
createShape = (function() {

    var addshapes = true,
        doCreateShape;

    setTimeout(
        function addListener() {
            var button = document.getElementById( 'stop' );
            if ( button ) {
                button.addEventListener( 'click', function() { addshapes = false; } );
            } else {
                setTimeout( addListener );
            }
        }
    );

    doCreateShape = function() {
        var shape, material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ opacity: 0, transparent: true });
        var minR = 5, maxR = 10;
        var minVertices = 4, maxVertices = 6;
        var sphere = randomSphereInBox(minR, maxR, {vertex3A: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), vertex3B: new THREE.Vector3(50, 50, 50)});
        var convex_geometry = randomConvexInSphere(minVertices, maxVertices, sphere);
        shape = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
            convex_geometry,
            material
        );

        shape.material.color.setRGB( Math.random() * 100 / 100, Math.random() * 100 / 100, Math.random() * 100 / 100 );
        shape.castShadow = false;
        shape.receiveShadow = false;

        shape.position.set(
            Math.random() * 30 - 15,
            40,
            Math.random() * 30 - 15   
        );

        if ( addshapes ) {
            shape.addEventListener( 'ready', createShape );
        }

        scene.add( shape );

        new TWEEN.Tween(shape.material).to({opacity: 1}, 500).start();

        document.getElementById( 'shapecount' ).textContent = ( ++shapes ) + ' shapes created';
    };

    return function() {
        setTimeout( doCreateShape, 10 );
    };
})();
```

Is there any way to constrain all the objects within the container?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fact that the objects are bouncing out of the box is because you are overloading it to the point where the objects altogether are "too big" for the containement box, leading to leaks. I don't think there is a real fix to this as this is always a problem in physics engines, but it doesn't hurt to try and plug a hole, right?

You could try using the object's own `addEventListener` method to check for collisions with the containement box and if so, set the position of itself to the center of the containement box, avoiding any extra collisions for a while:

```
doCreateShape = function(){
    // ...

    shape.addEventListener('collision', function(collidedWith, lineVel, angleVel){
        if(collidedWith.material == wall_material){ // If it actually collided with a wall
            this.__dirtyPosition = true; // To actively change the object position
            this.position.x = 0;
            this.position.y = 40;
            this.position.z = 0;
        }
    });

    scene.add(shape);

    // ...
}
```

Just make sure that the `wall_material` variable is global.

Also, setting the restitution of **all objects** to `0` will lessen bouncing inside the container.